# Only list S3 Objects that match wildcard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to create an IAM policy that allows a user limited access to my bucket. I only want them to see specific objects that match a wildcard.

Assuming structure of

```
bucket
|_ users
  |_ userA
    |_ fileXYZ.txt
    |_ imageXYZ.png
    |_ fileY.txt 
  |_ userB
    |_ fileXYZ.txt
    |_ imageXYZ.png
    |_ fileY.txt
```

I want to allow the user to navigate to the userA dir but prevent them from seeing all the objects in userA dir and only let them see a subset that match the wildcard `*XYZ*` (yes yes, S3 doesn't have directories, just prefixes, but let call it a dir :))

I have tried this policy and I cannot see any objects in the bucket and get and error that the admin needs to grant `ListObject`. The policy otherwise works if I change the wildcard to a more open `*` allowing the operation of all objects.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:delimiter": "/",
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "users/",
                        "users/userA"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "users/userA/*XYZ*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to only _return_ a list of objects that match the wildcard, then unfortunately this is not possible. The way policies work is that they decide whether or not the user is permitted to make that particular API call, as an "all or nothing" response. Your above policies look perfectly fine, but they require the user to provide a specific prefix to allow the call to succeed. Policies will never filter the contents of the return response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Rotenstein pointed out, policy only determines if the call should succeed (all or nothing). It cannot filter the result to only certain files. Therefore, as long as there is at least one file in the directory that is restricted, the user will get an error.

Based on this, alternatively what you can do is structure them a bit differently. This ensures that there are no restricted files in the directory that the user can access, i.e., `users/userA/visible_files`.

```
bucket
|_ users
  |_ userA
    |_visible_files
      |_ fileXYZ.txt
      |_ imageXYZ.png
    |_ fileY.txt 
  |_ userB
    |_visible_files
      |_ fileXYZ.txt
      |_ imageXYZ.png
    |_ fileY.txt
```

This is also cleaner/simpler in my opinion, as the policy uses the prefix as the matching condition, instead of the filename. Hypothetical example, if we allow filenames matching `*public*` to be visible, what if someone added a `Republic_secret.txt` in the future. This would have been unintentionally made visible.